# Who pays for extra time spent on a defective product?

Tags: halacha, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

The scenario: a guy charges $50 an hour, offers to replace a computer disk with a bigger one. For convenience, he also buys the new drive for the client from a supplier. After three hours of work (including testing and retesting), the disk turns out to be defective and needs replacement. The guy reaches the supplier and replaces the disk. He spends two hours actually replacing the drive.

The question: who pays for the first three hours?

Does it make a difference if he's a Sachir (charging per hour) or a Kablan (charging per work)?

I'm not interested here in the Halachic answer per se, I would like to see sources for coping with this case Halachicly.

Comment: He charges per hour as he doesn't know the amount of copying and the speed of the client's computer.